# question on Volley request Android studio

Tags: android, json, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I just want to get a sense of why `System.out.println("the number test is "+test);` doesn't return 3 in this case but 0 instead. Does it have something with the flow of volley requests? Thanks. If I actually put the system println in another method that is not oncreate, say inside a button on-click method, then it will print out 3 which is what I want

```
package com.app.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RequestQueue queue;
    int test =0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loadData();

        System.out.println("the number test is "+test);
    }

    public void loadData()
    {

        queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        String url =some json url with a json array;
        JsonObjectRequest request  = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray(name of json array);

                    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
                        test=test+1;
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        queue.add(request);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Volley requests are asynchronous, which means the code in your response listener may execute at a later time, not immediately. But you're printing immediately. You're printing value before it is even set. Remove the print statement, move it to:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray(name of json array);

        for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
            test=test+1;
        }
        here >>>>>>> System.out.println("the number test is "+test);
    } catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Than you very much!

Comment: mark it accepted if this solves your problem :)